# Linq Insert with string variable column name

Tags: c#, linq, insert

I want to pass a column name and value to a function that will update a table using LINQ.

I have the code below but don't know how to implement the string variable column name

```
private static void update(string key, string value)
    {
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken();

        accessToken.<key variable should go here> = value;

        QBAccessTokensDataContext db = new QBAccessTokensDataContext();
        db.AccessTokens.InsertOnSubmit(accessToken);
        db.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) for accessing a property in C# at runtime with reflection.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @nedmund

Comment: Is AccessToken a dictionary or dictionary like where you can do this `accessToken[key]=value;`?

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes, I'm updating the values of a dictionary to a db

Answer (score 0):

Add one more property to your class AccessToken with Key name and store the value